# Postal code database normalisation

Tags: normalization

With reference to localities and postal codes

Each postal code can have one more localities
Each locality can have one or more postal codes

Accordingly should this be created as a M:M scenario with a 3rd join table 'areas'?

The postal code table would only have a single column being the postal code itself and the locality table would also only have a single column being the locality name.

The alternative is a single table including both but it would result in repeated data.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

The question you have asked leaves open mostly to opinion. There are many factors that might make you lower the normalization based on the goals of how you plan to query the data.

Traditional normalization usually suggest the M:M scenario is correct, but that leaves applications constantly joining 3 tables to relate the information, and that may not be the most efficient if the applications do this in high frequency.

The alternative of a single table with repeated data could be optimal if accompanied by well designed non-clustered indexing so that joins are minimized and index seeks optimized in execution plans. However, storage would be taxed due to the non-clustered indexed, and apps of course have to know that the data coming back could be duped. But if the point is simply validating if a locality is within a zip code, this is expected.

Short story, there is the textbook answer in a perfect world, and then practically there may be other factors of performance, storage, query optimization, and application tendencies that could make lower normal forms preferable for certain situations.